# Cant see the Recent updates after Replacing Existing files in setup project

Tags: c#, installation, windows

I have created a setup project for Windows Application . I have set following property to replace the existing version with the new version.

```
RemovePreviousversion=True;
Productcode=change;
```

But when I run `exe` from new installed version. I cannot see my new updates. It gives me the output of previous version!

The whole Explanation is Here

I have RemovePreviousVersions set to TRUE and InstallAllUsers set to TRUE.

When I need to do a new release, I update the Version field with a new version number in the installer and VS prompts me to update the product code, to which I answer YES.  I have verified that it does indeed change the product code, but the package code also gets changed with it (verified by diffing project files using sourcesafe).

The UpgradeCode never changes between versions.

My version number changes are of the form:  "1.1.2"  -> "1.1.3" for example (just in case that has anything to do with it).

So only 3 fields are different between builds:  ProductCode, PackageCode, and ProductVersion.

When I've done all that, I build the installer.
When I install the new version (I always install for all users and always into the same directory), I have seen three different results at various times:

1. It will appear to in install the new version, but I really end up with the old files still there (and one instance in the add/remove programs).
2. I end up with 2 instances of the app in the add/remove programs, both with the same name, and both pointing to the same directory.
3. It will uninstall the old one first and then install the new one (what it is supposed to do).

It is very frustrating to explain to users that to be safe, they have to uninstall the old manually before installing a new release because I have to tell them "it doesn't always uninstall the old one like it is supposed to".

Any suggestions?  Why isn't this working?  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I Found answer.

Also need to change **AssemblyVersion** and **AssemblyFileVersion** in AssemblyInfo.cs